# swing ArrayList ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, search, arraylist

I have to enter student names and grades. At the beginning I've to set up for the user to input any amount between 2 and 25. After that the name and grades are populated in the text fields.

At the end I've to produce the results containing highest, lowest and average grades. Which I have done on the hidden text area but how can I make that visible when the user clicks on the Print out results button?

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays.*;

public class Grades extends JFrame
    {
    String names;
    int results=0;
    int count = 0;
    int a;
    double average;
    int sum=0;
    ArrayList<String> nm = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer>gr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //declare Buttons
    private JTextField t1, name, grades, searchtxt;
    private JLabel lbl1, namelbl, gradelbl, label1, searchlbl;
    String searchName;
    JButton b;
    JTextArea display = new JTextArea(30,30);
    //constructor
    public Grades()
        {
        super("Grades");

        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        lbl1 = new JLabel("Please enter a number of results");
        c. add(lbl1);

        t1 = new JTextField (2);
        c. add(t1);

        namelbl = new JLabel("Please enter student's name");
        c. add(namelbl);

        name = new JTextField (10);
        c. add(name);

        gradelbl = new JLabel("Please enter student's grade");
        c. add(gradelbl);

        grades = new JTextField (10);
        c. add(grades);

        label1= new JLabel("You have all the results entered ");
        label1.setForeground(Color.red);
        label1.setVisible(false);
        c.add(label1);

        b = new JButton("Print out the results");
        c.add(b);
        b.setVisible(false);

        searchlbl = new JLabel("Please enter the name to search for");
        c.add(searchlbl);

        searchtxt = new JTextField(10);
        c.add(searchtxt);

        display.setVisible(false);
        c.add(display);

        //create an instance of inner class ButtonHandler
        //to use for button event handling
        ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();

        t1.addActionListener(handler);
        name.addActionListener(handler);
        grades.addActionListener(handler);
        searchtxt.addActionListener(handler);
        b.addActionListener(handler);

        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);
        }

    public static void main (String args [])
        {
        Grades app = new Grades();
        app.addWindowListener(
        new WindowAdapter()
            {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
                {
                System.exit(0);
                }
            });
        }

    //inner class for button event handling
    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
        {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {
            Container c = getContentPane();
                if(e.getSource() == t1)
                    {
                    a = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
                    if (a < 2 || a > 25)
                        {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered wrong value. Please re- enter 2 to 25");
                        t1.requestFocusInWindow();
                        t1.setText("");
                        a = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
                        }
                        t1.setEditable(false);
                        name.requestFocusInWindow();
                        }

                if(e.getSource() == name)
                    {
                    names = name.getText();
                    grades.requestFocusInWindow();
                    grades.setText("");
                    nm.add(names);
                    }

                if(e.getSource() == grades)
                    {
                    try{

                    results = Integer.parseInt(grades.getText());
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please re- enter digits 0 to 100 only");
                    grades.requestFocusInWindow();
                    grades.setText("");
                    results = Integer.parseInt(grades.getText());
                }

                    if(results < 0 || results > 100)
                        {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered wrong value. 0 to 100 only");
                        grades.requestFocusInWindow();
                        grades.setText("");
                        results = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            gr.add(results);
                            count++;
                            sum=sum+results;
                            name.requestFocusInWindow();
                            name.setText("");


                        }

            if(count==a)
                {
                name.setEditable(false);
                label1.setVisible(true);
                grades.setText("");
                grades.setEditable(false);
                b.setVisible(true);
                System.out.println(nm);
                System.out.println(gr);

    Collections.sort(nm); // Sort the arraylist
    System.out.println(nm);
//int index = Collections.binarySearch(nm, searchName);
     //   System.out.println(index);

        if(e.getSource()==b)
        {
            display.setVisible(true);
        }

        int highest = gr.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < gr.size(); i++){
            int curValue = gr.get(i);
            if (curValue > highest) {
                highest = curValue;

            }

      display.setText("highest grades = " + highest );
}

        int smallest = gr.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < gr.size(); i++){
            int curValue = gr.get(i);
            if (curValue < smallest) {
                smallest = curValue;

            }
}
      display.append("\n"+"Smallest grades = " + smallest );


display.append("\n"+"Average = " + (double)sum/count);

}}
}

    }           }
```

Comment: *"Also, I've to let.."* You seem to be confusing SO with a help desk. Let's concentrate on the actual question and if you need help with the other, post it on a separate question thread - with a specific question..

Comment: *"..hidden text area but how can I make that visible.."* The first few strategies you might consider. 1) Put the text area into the layout / panel at app. start up with no text, then put the text into it it after the sorting etc. 2) Put the text area in a card layout and have another card as a blank panel to show initially, flip the cards to the text area after the sort. 3) Pop the text area in a dialog or option pane. ..

Comment: your question is pretty simple: "how can I make that visible when the user clicks on the Print out results button". So why did you post such a wall of code? Isolate the code to what is minimum relevant to the question. Good Luck...